# ((h=h+1)) is syntax error in shell script but not at the terminal

Tags: shell

[image]I expect the value to be incremented but get the same value of `h` i.e. `9`. When I tried this directly in terminal it's working fine but after writing in shell file value remains same. Please tell me how to increment using this method only. `i=$((i+1))` is also working.

```
h=9
echo $h

((h=h+1))
echo $h

((h=h+8))
echo $h
```

Comment: Using VI or another editor is irrelevant. Your code is working....assuming that the last line is a copy paste error. The statement "echo" has to be on its own line.

Comment: Always put output, which is not desired, along with output which is actually desired.

Comment: Are you perhaps running your code in sh instead of bash? There's some bash-only syntax here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes I was trying to run it as "sh filename.sh" as my teacher did and got the desired output. When I used "bash filename.sh" or "./filename.sh" it is working properly.

Comment: The post title should describe your question or problem well enough so that readers get the gist of what it's about ("Problem with Java function" is not very descriptive). See: [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)

Comment: `sh filename` won't work with `((h=h+1))`. POSIX shell only supports `$((...))`. All other uses are not required to be supported by `sh`. Now it depends what shell you are actually invoking with `sh` (e.g. `Bourne Shell`, `ash`, `dash`, etc..) as shells are free to provide extensions, but extensions are not guaranteed. See, e.g. [2.6.4 Arithmetic Expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) about 1/2 way down.

Answer (score 2):

This is a difference between `sh` and `bash`.

The POSIX sh standard only requires `h=$(( h + 1 ))` to work. It *does not* require `(( h = h + 1 ))` to work.

*Bash*, however, supports `(( h = h + 1 ))`. If you write a script using this syntax, you need to run it in bash -- not in sh -- to operate correctly.

That means you should run `bash yourscript` instead of `sh yourscript`, and start the script with a shebang such as `#!/usr/bin/env bash` to tell it to use bash as its interpreter when run as an executable.

Answer (score -2):

Simply copy pasted your code and got the below mentioned error

```
-bash-4.2$ cat test1.sh 
#!/bin/bash

h=9

echo $h

((h=h+1))

((h=h+8)) echo $h
-bash-4.2$ ./test1.sh 
9
./test1.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `echo'
./test1.sh: line 9: `((h=h+8)) echo $h'
-bash-4.2$
```

That is because, your syntax is not the correct way to add two values. Have a read [here](https://tecadmin.net/bash-add-two-integers/) for more details.

Added the required `echo` check and used correct syntax, and it gave the below result

```
-bash-4.2$ cat test1.sh 
#!/bin/bash

h=9

echo $h

h=$(($h + 1))

echo $h

h=$(($h + 8))

echo $h
-bash-4.2$ ./test1.sh 
9
10
18
-bash-4.2$
```

You can use `expr` too.

```
h=`expr $h + 1`
```

Comment: That was an artifact of how the question was formatted, not the code the OP was actually running.

Comment: The original syntax is fine when the code is _actually run in bash_ as long as you include the newline. It's only broken in sh.

Comment: And `expr` should never be recommended to anyone: As an external command, the overhead involved in its use is unjustifiable. It's an artifact of the 1970s; with the 1992 publication of a standard for POSIX sh (with built-in integer math), its use for arithmetic became obsolete.